# How to automatically generate sqlalchemy relationships on set and create?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm not really sure how to word the title for this question, but hopefully I can explain what I am trying to do.

I have the following many-to-one relationship between a Track and Album:

```py
class Album(Base):
    __tablename__ = "albums"

    artist = Column(String, nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    title = Column(String, nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    year = Column(Integer, nullable=False, primary_key=True)

    tracks = relationship(
        "Track", back_populates="_album_obj", cascade="all, delete-orphan"
    )

class Track(Base):
    __tablename__ = "tracks"

    # track_num + Album = unique track
    track_num = Column(Integer, nullable=False, primary_key=True, autoincrement=False)
    albumartist = Column(String, nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    album = Column(String, nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    year = Column(Integer, nullable=False, primary_key=True, autoincrement=False)

    artist = Column(String, nullable=False, default="")
    title = Column(String, nullable=False, default="")

    _album_obj = relationship("Album", back_populates="tracks")

    __table_args__ = (
        ForeignKeyConstraint(
            [albumartist, album, year],
            [Album.artist, Album.title, Album.year],
        ),
    )
```

A couple behaviors I am after:

1. When creating a Track, an associated Album is also created.

   - This part is actually easy if I just add an `self._album_obj = Album(...)` to Track's `__init__`
2. When editing an album attribute through a Track, a new Album is created with that attribute rather than editing the existing Album.

   - This part I am not too sure how to best achieve. Maybe somehow leveraging [hybrid attributes](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/hybrid.html)? Or perhaps using some (unknown to me) feature of relationships or foreign keys? Or is this a database design issue that could be achieved if I refactor my models?

Hopefully the following will demonstrate the behavior I'm after:

```py
track = Track(track_num=1, albumartist="K.Dot", album="GKMC", year=2012)
assert track._album_obj.title == track.album
album1 = track._album_obj

track.album = "TPAB"
assert track._album_obj.title == track.album
assert album1 is not track._album_obj
```

Comment: Why do you  duplicate title artist and year in the tracks table?

Comment: @snakecharmerb because it's more natural to say `Track.albumartist` as opposed to `Track.album.artist`. This applies to the other album fields as well. I'd like them to be directly accessible from a Track.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a full working script:

```py
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid import hybrid_property
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.schema import ForeignKeyConstraint

Session = sessionmaker()
Base = declarative_base()


class Album(Base):

    __tablename__ = "albums"

    artist = Column(String, nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    title = Column(String, nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    year = Column(Integer, nullable=False, primary_key=True)

    tracks = relationship(
        "Track", back_populates="_album_obj", cascade="all, delete-orphan"
    )

    def __init__(self, artist: str, title: str, year: int):
        self.artist = artist
        self.title = title
        self.year = year


class Track(Base):  # noqa: WPS230
    __tablename__ = "tracks"

    # track_num + Album = unique track
    track_num = Column(Integer, nullable=False, primary_key=True, autoincrement=False)
    _albumartist = Column(String, nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    _album = Column(String, nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    _year = Column(Integer, nullable=False, primary_key=True, autoincrement=False)

    artist = Column(String, nullable=False, default="")
    title = Column(String, nullable=False, default="")

    _album_obj = relationship("Album", back_populates="tracks")

    __table_args__ = (
        ForeignKeyConstraint(
            [_albumartist, _album, _year],  # type: ignore
            [Album.artist, Album.title, Album.year],
        ),
    )

    @hybrid_property
    def album(self) -> str:
        return self._album_obj.title

    @album.setter
    def album(self, new_album_title: str):
        self._album_obj = Album(
            artist=self.albumartist, title=new_album_title, year=self.year
        )

    @hybrid_property
    def albumartist(self) -> str:
        return self._album_obj.artist

    @albumartist.setter
    def albumartist(self, new_albumartist: str):
        self._album_obj = Album(
            artist=new_albumartist, title=self.album, year=self.year
        )

    @hybrid_property
    def year(self) -> int:
        return self._album_obj.year

    @year.setter
    def year(self, new_album_year: str):
        self._album_obj = Album(
            artist=self.albumartist, title=self.album, year=new_album_year
        )

    def __init__(self, album: str, albumartist: str, track_num: int, year: int):
        self._album_obj = Album(artist=albumartist, title=album, year=year)
        self.track_num = track_num
        self._album = album
        self._albumartist = albumartist
        self._year = year


engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("sqlite:///:memory:", echo=True)
Session.configure(bind=engine)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
session = Session()

track = Track(track_num=1, albumartist="K.Dot", album="GKMC", year=2012)
assert track._album_obj.title == track.album
album1 = track._album_obj

track.album = "TPAB"
assert track._album_obj.title == track.album
assert album1 is not track._album_obj
```

There are a few important changes that made this possible.

1. Make the Track foreign keys "private" meaning we should not be setting these directly. Allow the ORM to populate these behind the scenes. The only exception I've found is on `init`. Since the foreign keys double as the Track's primary keys, not setting them prior to attaching the Track to a session will create issues if using `session.merge()`.
2. With the above, create [hybrid properties](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/hybrid.html#module-sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid) to allow access to these attributes through the Album relationship.
3. Create setters for the hybrid properties that will instantiate a new Album on set.